# Adding FBML to users wall post?

Tags: facebook

When posting to the users wall can I include FBML? i.e. "Mick just scored the high score on {GAME}"?

I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the details about the allowed content of the various fields in a stream post are available in [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments).

### EDIT

> **description:** Descriptive text about
>   the story. This field can contain
>   ***plain text only*** and should be no
>   longer than is necessary for a reader
>   to understand the story. The
>   description can contain up to 1,000
>   characters, but Facebook displays the
>   first 300 or so characters of text by
>   default; users can see the remaining
>   text by clicking a "See More" link
>   that we append automatically to long
>   stories, or attachments with more than
>   one image.

Comment: I looked through that page before I posted but it mentions nothing about including FBML. My question was "Can I add FBML to the wall posts".

I have seen Farmville do it, but there is no documentation that explains or demonstrates.

James

Comment: No you haven't seen Farmville do it.  The `message` field, and both the `description` and `caption` fields of attachments are all plain-text only.  The `caption` field allows the `{*actor*}` token but that's it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. I seen it in the description.

Comment: No, you haven't.  Not recently, at least.  Maybe in a older version when Facebook still handled wall posts via template bundles (which allowed FBML), but that functionality has been deprecated for a while now.  I'm adding a quote to my post...

Comment: Sorry just seen you edited the comment about {*actor*}. Thanks for the responses. Much appreciated.

Comment: No offense, but you shouldn't have needed to see that I edited my comment.  It's all in the documentation I linked in my original answer which you allegedly "looked through before posting".